# How to create variable based on no of column in an excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Below is the code to get no of last used column

```
Dim lastColumn As Integer

 lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

which return suppose 6 .My use case is  based on return value i want to create that no of long variable in vba. How to do that please help

Comment: Could you explain it one more time please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be defining 1 array variable of long data type.

For eg.

```
Sub test()

' Get last column number
Dim lastColumn As Integer
lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

' Create a long data type array with limit equal last column number
Dim arrColVars(lastColumn) as Long

' Perform operations or assignment on variables
' arrColVars(0) = 123
' arrColVars(1) = 456
' ...
' arrColVars(n) = 789

End Sub
```

**Note:**

- All array indexes declared but not defined will default to a value of zero
  (0).
- If you refer to an array index beyond the array limit specified, you
  will get an error 'Subscript out of range'.